# http request path with custom param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, https

I'm trying to pass a value in a URL using Net::HTTP::Get in Ruby, where i need to let this way:

[https://cdpj.partners.bancointer.com.br/pix/v2/webhook/{18497418000111}](https://cdpj.partners.bancointer.com.br/pix/v2/webhook/%7B18497418000111%7D)

But i don't know how to do it, this is my code:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'json'  

uri = URI.parse("https://cdpj.partners.bancointer.com.br/pix/v2/webhook/{18497418000111}")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request["Authorization"] = "Bearer #{'1fd64146-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx997c170'}"
request["Accept"] = "application/vnd.bluebadge-api.v1+json"
response = http.request(request)
```

When i try do do it i receive this message:
bad URI(is not URI?): "https://cdpj.partners.bancointer.com.br/pix/v2/webhook/{18497418000111}"

But if i try to insert my param inside the url, everything works as expected:
[image]

basically my problem is, how to add this part of my url in my URI: {18497418000111}
**with json i need to add a key/value, but in my example i need to pass only the value.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the curly brackets need to be in there? In your Postman example you also do get a 404 Not Found, is that expected?

Comment: fixed! thanks my dear friend, we found the error!

Answer (score 0):

> When i try do do it i receive this message: bad URI(is not URI?):
> "https://cdpj.partners.bancointer.com.br/pix/v2/webhook/{18497418000111}"

If you encode the `{` and `}` characters with their hex codes then it works. Please see the output below from `irb`.

**Before encoding**

```
3.1.2 :013 > uri = URI.parse('https://cdpj.partners.bancointer.com.br/pix/v2/webhook/{18497418000111}')
.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:67:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): "https://cdpj.partners.bancointer.com.br/pix/v2/webhook/{18497418000111}" (URI::InvalidURIError)
```

**After encoding**

```
3.1.2 :015 > uri = URI.parse("https://cdpj.partners.bancointer.com.br/pix/v2/webhook/%7B18497418000111%7D")
 => #<URI::HTTPS https://cdpj.partners.bancointer.com.br/pix/v2/webhook/%7B18497418000111%7D> 
3.1.2 :016 > http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
3.1.2 :017 > http.use_ssl = true
 => true 
3.1.2 :018 > request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
 => #<Net::HTTP::Get GET> 
3.1.2 :019 > request["Authorization"] = "Bearer #{'1fd64146-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx997c170'}"
3.1.2 :020 > request["Accept"] = "application/vnd.bluebadge-api.v1+json"
 => "application/vnd.bluebadge-api.v1+json" 
3.1.2 :021 > response = http.request(request)
 => #<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true> 
3.1.2 :022 >
```